# CALayer vs. Layer-backed NSView Performance

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I plan to have a view that could contain multiple hundreds of `CALayer` objects inside and next to each other. Thus this has to be as performant as possible. Those layers aren't very complex. They are opaque and could be text or shape layers. This amount of layers has to get layouted. I would use `CAConstraints` for this.

From Apples Docs:

> Important: In OS X v10.8 and later, it is recommended that you minimize your use of layer hierarchies and just use layer-backed views. The layer redraw policies introduced in that version of OS X let you customize the behavior of your layer-backed views and still get the kind of performance you might have gotten previously using standalone layers.

I know that `CALayer` objects are more lightweight than views. I am not sure *why* we should use layer-backed views instead of layers directly. Is it for the ease of use with Auto Layout or are there more performance / memory related reasons for this statement? I would like to get the best performance possible, as this code will run on both OS X and iOS.

Which way should I go? Auto Layout and layer-backed `NSViews` or custom `CALayer` hierarchy?

Comment: CAConstraints are not available on iOS. Sounds like they are saying layer-backed views are more flexible but can give you the same performance.

Comment: I Should have looked for the availability of CAConstraints.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with layer backed views. Performance is very good so far. The views are all layed out by stackViews.